# virtualhost won't redirect

Tags: redirect, apache2, virtualhost

Here's a clip of my virtualhost file:

```
  SeverName domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com

  <Directory />
     Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\./]+\.[^\./]+$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . archive.php [L]
  </Directory>
```

domain.com doesn't redirect to www.domain.com.

The part below works fine though, redirecting a page to archive.php.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your first RewriteCond: in the match pattern, `{` should be `[`.

Comment: good catch Joachim. However, still didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does the rule work if you remove the `/` from the match pattern?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the request is to http://domain.com with no trailing `/`, then the rule as you wrote it with a leading `/` might not match.  Or, mod_rewrite may remove the leading `/`, since you have `RewriteBase /` in a `<Directory>` context.  This is what the [RewriteRule docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) ("What is Matched?" box) seem to say.